# Find by _id on an array of objects in mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to find the id of an object inside an array of objects. That _id has the same field name _id as others in the document.
This is my model (brief)

```
var CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  beName: String,
  beLink: String,
  cards: [{ 
    cardType: String,
    cardBundle: String
  }]
```

This is an sample of my database content

```
_id: ObjectId(5a52540638086448bf4235e8)
beName: Name1
beLink: Link1
cards: Array
 0: Object
    cardType: type1
    cardBundle: 1
    _id: ObjectId(5a526749d0ddab4bcdcc1556)
 1: Object
    cardType: type2
    cardBundle: 1
    _id: ObjectId(5a526749d0ddab4bcdcc1557)

...

_id: ObjectId(5a52540638086448bf4235e9)
beName: Namex
beLink: Linkx
cards: Array
 0: Object
    cardType: typex
    cardBundle: x
    _id: ObjectId(5a526749d0ddab4bcdcc1598)
 1: Object
    cardType: type2
    cardBundle: 1
    _id: ObjectId(5a526749d0ddab4bcdcc1599)
```

I'm trying to find the id of an specific card like this

```
Cards.find({ _id: req.params.id}, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
```

But I get an empty result

I also tried

```
Cards.find({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id)}...
```

Comment: you know the `_id` of card object?

Comment: yes, i know the card id, it's part of the url query

Comment: that _id on the cards object is being generated by mongo, its not part of my mongoose schema

Comment: Are you trying to search the ids in the cards array ? or in the main document ? If its the id in array, you can try `Cards.find().select({'cards': {$elemMatch: {'_id':mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}}})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use an `aggregate` function to `$unwind` the array of cards to find the matching card based on `_id`.

so, in mongoose instead of `find` use `aggregate` pipeline

sample doc

```
> db.cards.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52f4136fe82b42b7439a21"),
    "beName" : "Name1",
    "beLink" : "Link1",
    "cards" : [
        {
            "cardType" : "type1",
            "cardBundle" : 1,
            "_id" : "5a52f3a66f112b42b7439a20"
        },
        {
            "cardType" : "type2",
            "cardBundle" : 1,
            "_id" : "5a52f3a66f112b42b7439a21"
        }
    ]
}
```

aggregate function

```
> db.cards.aggregate([{$unwind: "$cards"}, {$match:{"cards._id" : "5a52f3a66f112b42b7439a20"}}] )
```

result doc

```
> db.cards.aggregate([{$unwind: "$cards"}, {$match:{"cards._id" : "5a52f3a66f112b42b7439a20"}}] ).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a52f4136fe82b42b7439a21"),
    "beName" : "Name1",
    "beLink" : "Link1",
    "cards" : {
        "cardType" : "type1",
        "cardBundle" : 1,
        "_id" : "5a52f3a66f112b42b7439a20"
    }
}
>
```

You can optimise it further if you know the parent `_id`, in the aggregate pipeline `$match` by parent `_id`, then `$unwind`, then `$match` on array card `_id`

```
> db.cards.aggregate([{$match:{"_id":ObjectId("5a52f4136fe82b42b7439a21")}},{$unwind: "$cards"}, {$match:{"cards._id" : "5a52f3a66f112b42b7439a20"}}] )
```

Answer (score 4):

Question is a bit vague, but by looking at other answers and having the card's _id in the url, I guess you have the card _id and you want to find the parent document. if so, then you don't need an aggregate. a find query does the job:

```html
db.cards.find({"cards._id": _id})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like:

```
const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID,

/* some other statements */

let cardId = new ObjectId(req.params.id)
Cards.find({ _id: cardId}, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
});
```

For Reference: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html