# How can I find object ID of MMT4 by nodeJS and mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I find object ID of MMT4 by nodeJS and mongoDB ?
[image]

Thank you for your help ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I worked on your question and if you are using mongodb and nodejs you can do the following stpes:

1. using **$match** and **$unwind** aggregations to find the object that match with title **MMT4**:

   db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$children"}, {$match: {"children.title": "MMT4"}}])

   **Notice**: I wrote the above syntax in mongodb shell you can write it in JS with **mongoose** library.
2. the result is an object with children array that contain just **MMT4** object. you can iterate in this single element array using JS to get **_id** of the MMT4

**reference**: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144183/find-by-id-on-an-array-of-objects-in-mongodb-database)