# how to get data of inside the array of objects in mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am working in a MERN project and i want to fetch data from inside the array of objects through the inside objectid.

**My model view**

[image]

**I want to fetch `name:"vikash"` and `attendance:"present"` through the `objectid:"63cbb3b15cd59c7810ab89a2`**

**I had tried two types of methods from previous [stackoverfow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144183/find-by-id-on-an-array-of-objects-in-mongodb-database) solution but they didn't work for me**

```
app.get('/stud/:id', (req, res) => {
    ProjectSchema.find({"projectmembers._id":req.params._id}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.status(200).send(data);
    });
})
```

**the second one is**

```
app.get('/stu/:id', (req, res) => {
    ProjectSchema.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind:"$projectmembers"
        },
        {$match : {
            "projectmembers._id" : req.params._id
        }}
    ], (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        res.status(200).send(data);
    });
})
```

**The output of both code is `[]`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was also a typo in your code. The params name is `id`, so it should be `req.params.id` and not `req.params._id` - that's probably the reason why you were receiving an empty array.

For your case, you can `filter` the result so that you only receive the project member of a specific id through aggregation.

For example:

```
    app.get('/stu/:id', (req, res) => {
    
        try {
          const student = await ProjectSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      projectmembers: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$projectmembers",
          as: "projectMember",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$projectMember._id",
              ObjectId(req.params.id)
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);

      if (!student)
        return res.status(400).json({
          success: false,
          message: "No student exists with this ID",
        });
        
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Student Found",
        studentDetails: student,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Error encountered whilst finding student",
        error: err,
      });
    }
  });
```

You can see that there is a `$project` stage - what this does is tells mongo what you want to return. I wrote `_id: 0`, which tells mongo that you do not want to return the `document's _id` field. Then the `$filter` stage has an `input` field, which tells mongo what to filter - in our case `projectmembers`. In the `$as` field is the name of the variable for each item in your `projectmembers` array, which I named `projectMember` - you could name it anything you like. Then we can access each item via the variable named `projectMember` in our condition statement `cond` we passed an `$eq` condition, which checks the `projectmembers` array for any `$$projectMember._id` (in the `eq` condition, we prefix `projectMember.id` with two `$$` in order to access it) which is equal to `req.params.id`.

To access the ObjectId, you will need to import it at the top of your file:

```
const { ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
```

Finally, you can also see how the mongo aggregation works here at [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NQfGjGlLeGb) and play around with it.

Comment: @scot...thanks for your answer..actually i am new to mongo so..... i got the output is  ```{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Student Found",
    "studentDetails": []
}```....  how to retrieve the backend data

Comment: No problem. Have you console logged req.params.id to make sure you are receiving the correct value?

Comment: yes i am getting the id

Comment: can you please console.log `student` after the await call and see what the output is?

Comment: i got like this ```[]```

Comment: Hi Anita - apologies, I originally misread part of your question. I have edited my answer and it should work now. I have also update the mongoplayground link in my answer so you can see how the aggregation works.